# javascript two functions on click

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

All I want is a simple form that a person has to agree to check the box before info is submitted. However, The code for the javascript works on the email validation and all text boxes but not for the checkbox. It actually alerts but then submits the info anyway.

How do I call these two functions at same time? Or better yet how do I validate and tall fields are filled in and Box is checked?

HTML form with Java. See I have two javacodes in there. This code below does not work.

```
<input name="imageField" type="image" id="imageField" onclick="if(!form2.checkbox.checked){alert('You must agree to the terms first.');} MM_validateForm('FullName','','R','Email','','RisEmail','Password','','R','Phone','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" src="images/Submit.png" />
```

javacript for validation:

```
function MM_validateForm() 
{ 
    if (document.getElementById)
    {
        var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
        for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) 
        { 
            test=args[i+2]; 
            val=document.getElementById(args[i]);

            if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") 
            {
                if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) 
                { 
                    p=val.indexOf('@');
                    if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) 
                        errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
                } 
                else if (test!='R') 
                { 
                    num = parseFloat(val);
                    if (isNaN(val)) 
                        errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
                    if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) 
                    { 
                        p=test.indexOf(':');
                        min=test.substring(8,p); 
                        max=test.substring(p+1);
                        if (num<min || max<num) 
                            errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') 
                errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
        } 

        if (errors) 
            alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);

        document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
    } 
}
```

Comment: `return false` after the alert. And please look into getting rid of that macromedia function...

Comment: Try to put the two function in one then call that function.

Comment: @Papa If that was your actual code then you really need to start using proper indentation!

Comment: Well I don't know javascript too well. I am using macromedia to generate it and try to figure it out but that is how they code it for you. I just copied and pasted. I never usually touch it but needed to this time. Sorry

Comment: Okay, then. My first tip still stands, `alert('You must agree to the terms first.'); return false;`. That might solve your issue.

Comment: I tried that but the issue is it always submits if text boxes are valid but checkbox is not checked. I get the alert but then it submits anyway. Here is the code: if(!form2.checkbox.checked){alert('You must agree to the terms first.');}

Comment: try `getElementById` then check if the value is checked.

Comment: here: [link]http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php

Comment: Why not take the plunge and validate it with a jQuery plugin? http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ The auto-generated stuff will usually bite and that's on  good day.